# Trying to get property of non-object when its clearly a property on an object

Tags: php

Good day, Just a quick one, why is it that Im getting "Trying to get property of non-object" error when Im accessing my object.

echo print_r($bill['transactions'])

result below:

```
Array
(
[transactions] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [vendor] => 1
                [total] => 8934
                [payment_terms] => 60
                [date_at] => 2015-02-09 00:00:00
                [date_due] => 2015-03-11 00:00:00
            )

        [past_due] => 44
    )

[totalAccount] => 8934
[vendor] => Sample Supplier Co.
)
1
```

and when I try to loop it using this code

```
 @foreach($bill['transactions'] as $t)
 <td><?php print_r($t); ?></td>
 @endforeach
```

result below:

```
stdClass Object
(
[vendor] => 1
[total] => 8934
[payment_terms] => 60
[date_at] => 2015-02-09 00:00:00
[date_due] => 2015-03-11 00:00:00
)
1
```

then when i finally use the -> to access its property

```
@foreach($bill['transactions'] as $t)
<td><?php echo $t->vendor; ?></td>
@endforeach
```

I then get the error. by the way Im using laravel blade

Comment: show us complete object there is no transaction in it

Comment: helle @VarunNaharia the above objects was the $t's content when I used print_r($t);

Comment: no need to feed it in a foreach, use the object with its properties outright

Comment: hello @Ghost I need to feed it in a foreach loop so coz $bill['transactions'] is an array of object.

Comment: I will add details above coz it seems my question is not very clear here :) thanks for your time guys

Comment: $bill['transactions']  is not fully an array of objects, it is mixed array, you have [past_due] => 44 which is integer.

Comment: $bill['transactions']) has both array and object so can't use them directly in for each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Taalaibek said, the problem with your code is that you are trying to access a property of a non-object. Your array `$bill['transactions']` has two elements - an object and a number, 44. Unlike some other languages, such as JavaScript (and to a lesser extent, Java with boxing/unboxing), where primitive values are implicitly objects, only *objects* are objects in PHP. Trying to access the value of a non-object with `->` in PHP will throw an error. To reiterate, in JS, you could do

```
var x = 5;
alert(x.toString());
```

but in PHP, the following code will give you an error:

```
$x = 5;
echo $x->hello;
```

Note that while in Java, all objects inherit from a base class, this is not true in PHP. The objects that you create in PHP do not inherit from `stdClass`, and primitive values (such as 44) definitely do not.

You can amend your code as follows:

```
@foreach($bill['transactions'] as $t)
<td><?php if(is_object($t)) echo $t->vendor; ?></td>
@endforeach
```

using the [`is_object`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) function.